# Equal height divs kept together side-by-side always

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3.x and creating a common 3 column layout.  In desktop view I want all three divs in the same row and the same height.  When shrunk down to the smallest width I want the first two divs to always remain next to each other but the third drop below.  Always, the first two divs should be the same height.  If the second div is shorter than the first, the third div ends up underneath the second, to the right of the first.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
        <!-- keep these two divs together side by side and the same height -->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            this is panel one
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            this is panel two
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <!-- this div should be beside the other two on large screens and drop below on xsmall screens -->
        side bar ad
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is another way to visualize the issue.  The first two need to be the same height:  http://www.bootply.com/29cNrJrEwT

Comment: It feels like you're asking someone to do this work for you rather than actually asking a question.

Comment: No. it's called I've been doing trial and error for the past 6 hours and still cannot get it to work.  As many have said, you'd think by Bootstrap 3 someone would have added equal height divs as a standard feature.

Comment: This is why [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Examples) was created. It's not nearly as hard as it seems.

Answer (score 2):

**Connie DeCinko**, Hi there.
To have the divs flow like you ask here you would do that this way.
Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qehapvrs/)**.
You said that the first two blocks **should have the same height** so you would not have a issue with the 3rd block flowing below.
But, if say the second block is to be shorter than the first block then wrap the first 2 block in a `row` and also wrap the 3rd block in a `row` and add to the `row` for the 3rd block `col-xs-12` so when on small screens it takes up the full width.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 block1"><h2>Block 1</h2></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 block2"><h2>Block 2</h2></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 block3"><h2>Block 3</h2></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

**If you do actually want to have the second block shorter**.
Then you could do it this way.
Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36xz8vtr/)**.

**Note** this is **not** using Flex ... Flex does not have full browser support.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-8  text-center clear">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 block4"><h2>Block 1</h2></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 block5"><h2>Block 2</h2></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center clear">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 block6 "><h2>Block 3</h2></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox was created for this. Literally.

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/6ka86vfx/

- Define a flex container with `display: flex`
- Tell its children to `flex: 1`

  - Except the bigger children, they're `flex: 3` in this case
- Children can be flex containers too

  - It's children have `flex: 1` again, to make them equal size

Your class names aren't the most descriptive, but the CSS is otherwise very simple:

```
.row { /* flex container */
    display: flex;
}
.row > div { /* all its children */
    flex: 1;
}
.row > div:first-child { /* one of its children is bigger (3:1) and is a flex container itself */
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
}
.row > div:first-child > div { /* all its children are equal size */
    flex: 1;
}
```